# CiviEvent book multiple event at a single checkout

Tags: civievent, repeating-events

EDITED: We are using Eventcalender extension to display all events on one page.

For example Yoga Classes happens every week on Monday. Now for an attendee who would like to book 1st week, then 5th, 9th, 15th, 22nd and some more weeks of the year has to keep registering for each week. It could be frustrating for attendee to come back every-time & enter same details to register. We thought of creating repeating events. but that does not allow to register to select multiple events at single checkout. Is there any option where CiviEvent would act like a checkout? A good example of my idea is sagenda.com.  If not, how can I get an alternative checkout function like this? Or am I missing something in existing CiviEvent? Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: it would help me if you could show more clearly what the various options are. eg you say 'we have an event that runs every week', then you say 'to select multiple days'. So am not clear

Comment: Sorry! Edited the main post

Comment: would offering each week as a price set checkbox be useful?

Comment: Yes I thought of it. But would 52 items in a price set not be excessive ? Also specify date to each price set items would be a lot of manual work. Some date may need to be excluded.  And every time this type of repeated events will needed to do this type of manual adjustment of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was work on an Event Cart function for CiviEvent, but it was never completed.  However, there are folks who use it.  I would expect to put in some developer time if you want to use it.

Enable it at **Administer » CiviEvent » CiviEvent Component Settings** by checking **Use Shopping Cart Style Event Registration**.

There are some guides to using it from [Cividesk](https://www.cividesk.com/blog/post/adding-civicrm-shopping-cart) and in the [CiviCRM cookbook](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781782160441/8/ch08lvl1sec82/using-a-shopping-cart-and-drupal-views-for-event-registration), as well as some older [documentation](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviEvent+Cart+Checkout).

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what I am looking for. Is there a way to integrate with eventcalendar extension or similar. If you are willing to help developing please contact me

Comment: We did some analysis of Event Cart and advice was that it was going to be a lot of work, so we instead invested more effort in making Webform_civicrm work for multiple folk signing up for multiple events

Comment: @petednz-fuzion You should post that as an answer, I'd upvote it!

Comment: @petednz-fuzion thanks for your input. can you please add as answer on how I can use webform in my specific situation?

Comment: I found this checkout function is broken in CiviCRM 5.11+. So it didn’t really help. How much time and effort may it take for a developer to make it stable release? Anyone interested?

Answer (score 3):

Just so you know, there's two extensions currently under development for CiviCRM, and specifically that integrate with CiviCRM's Event Cart feature, that might meet some of your needs. They're under active development, and you can check them out on CiviCRM's GitLab.

[boxoffice](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/boxoffice): Provides a lighter workflow for the CiviCRM Event Cart. Designed for a ticket box office (ex: where you do not need the names of other participants).

[eventpack](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/eventpack): Provides a way to bundle events together (at a discounted price) in the CiviCRM Event Cart (and the Boxoffice extension).

Answer (score 0):

We did some analysis of Event Cart (April 2019) and advice was that it was going to be a lot of work, so we instead invested more effort in making Webform_civicrm work for multiple folk signing up for multiple events